# Draw object dynamically when dragging the mouse

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel, paint

I'm developing a Java program in Netbeans to draw a graph tree creating its nodes and edges and drawing it into a JPanel.

I'm having problems only dragging the nodes and the edges, because the image doesn't update - it suddenly disappears everything and I need to add a node or edge to watch the tree again.

What I found is that the error must be in the Graph.paint() function or something about repaint, revalidate... functions.

I've been looking for a solution here but I couldn't find anything that really solves it.

**GraphPanel** is the JPanel that manages the Graph.

**Graph** is the structure that stores all the nodes and edges

**Node** and **Edge** is the structure of the nodes and edges respectively.

My **GraphPanelMouseClicked** code is:
I post this code to show yow how I paint the nodes and so on [This works correctly]

```
private void GraphPanelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("Click X: " + evt.getX() + " , y: " + evt.getY());
    System.out.println("Click On Screen X: " + evt.getXOnScreen() + " , y: " + evt.getYOnScreen());

    switch(this.ButtonSelection){
        case OriHelperGUI.Select:
            break;
        case OriHelperGUI.AddNode:
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Node name: ");
            String weight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Node weight: ");
            Node n = new Node(new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY()), Integer.parseInt(weight), name);
            g.addNode(n);
            System.out.println("Nodo " + name + " añadido");
            break;
        case OriHelperGUI.AddEdge:
                for(Node node: g.getNodes()){
                    if(new Rectangle((int)(node.getPoint().getX() - node.getWeight()/2),(int)(node.getPoint().getY() - node.getWeight()/2), (int)node.getWeight(), (int)node.getWeight()).contains(new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY()))){
                       if(this.AddEdgeN1==null){
                           AddEdgeN1 = node; 
                           System.out.println(node.getName());
                       }
                       else{
                           if(AddEdgeN2==null){
                               AddEdgeN2 = node;
                               System.out.println("Uniendo " + AddEdgeN1.getName() + " a " + AddEdgeN2.getName());
                               g.addEdge(new Edge(AddEdgeN1, AddEdgeN2));
                               AddEdgeN1.addNeighbour(AddEdgeN2);
                               AddEdgeN2.addNeighbour(AddEdgeN1);
                               g.checkEdges();
                               AddEdgeN1 = null;
                               AddEdgeN2 = null;
                           }                               
                       }
                    }
                }                   
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    g.paint(GraphPanel.getGraphics());
    GraphPanel.revalidate();

}
```

My **GraphPanelMouseDragged** code is:
I think here is where it fails...

```
 private void GraphPanelMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(this.SelectedNode>=0){
        Node old = this.g.getNodes().get(this.SelectedNode);
        Node n = new Node(new Point(evt.getX(),evt.getY()),old.getWeight(),old.getName());            
        g.getNodes().set(this.SelectedNode, n);
        g.paint(GraphPanel.getGraphics());
        GraphPanel.revalidate();
    }
}
```

My **Graph** paint(g) and paintComponent(g) methods are [Not sure which one will be working when updating the image]:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    super.paint(g);
    for(Node n:nodes){
        n.paintNode(g);
    }
    for(Edge e:edges){
        e.paintEdge(g);
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    super.paint(g);
    for(Node n:nodes){
        n.paintNode(g);
    }
    for(Edge e:edges){
        e.paintEdge(g);
    }
}
```

**Node** paint(g) method:

```
public void paintNode(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // don't forget to call the super's method
    g.drawOval((int)(point.x -(weight/2)), (int)(point.y-(weight/2)), (int)weight, (int)weight);
    g.drawString(name, point.x, point.y);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // don't forget to call the super's method
    g.drawOval((int)(point.x -(weight/2)), (int)(point.y-(weight/2)), (int)weight, (int)weight);
    g.drawString(name, point.x, point.y);
    repaint();
}
```

Finally, my **Edge** paint(g) method is:

```
public void paintEdge(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // don't forget to call the super's method
    g.drawLine((int)n1.getPoint().getX(), (int)n1.getPoint().getY(), (int)n2.getPoint().getX(), (int)n2.getPoint().getY());
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // don't forget to call the super's method
    g.drawLine((int)n1.getPoint().getX(), (int)n1.getPoint().getY(), (int)n2.getPoint().getX(), (int)n2.getPoint().getY());
    repaint();
}
```

I also add a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP16E.gif) of the current program, to understand better my problem.

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).